# Passing argument of uint256 array

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

In Solidity what should be the correct format  when passing an array of uint256  in etherscan to a function?
Function

```
    function sendAmount(address[] memory recipients, uint256[] memory amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(recipients.length > 0, "No recipients specified.");
        require(amount.length > 0, "Amount should be greater than zero.");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
            _transfer(msg.sender, recipients[i], amount[i]);
        }
    }
```

I tried to pass, samples below, but all are getting an **invalid Big Number error**.

- ["500000000000000000000000000", "300000000000000000000000000"]
- ["0x1dcd6500", "0x11e1a300"]
- ['0x1dcd6500', '0x11e1a300']
- [0x1dcd6500, 0x1dcd6500]
- "[500000000000000000000000000, 300000000000000000000000000]"
- "[0x1dcd6500, 0x1dcd6500]"

[Screenshot of function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHpna.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[1,2,3] this should be correct. you can test it with this sample code on Remix.

```
contract ContractB  {
    address contractAddress = 0x9D7f74d0C41E726EC95884E0e97Fa6129e3b5E99;
    function total(uint[] memory numbers) public view returns (uint) {
        uint tot=0;
        for (uint i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            tot+=numbers[i];
        }
        return tot;
    }
}
```

when you call `total`, just pass [1,2,3] you will get 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a uint256[] array and you want to assign values to it, you need to provide values that are of the same i.e. type uint256. The values you provide should not be enclosed in quotation marks, as that would make them treated as strings instead of numerical values.

Instead of ["500000000000000000000000000", "300000000000000000000000000"], try taking the array as [500000000000000000000000000, 300000000000000000000000000]